# Draw with arbitrary shaped pen

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, drawing

I need to draw lines onto a bitmap using a custom aperture.  In the example below, there are two lines.  The left line is horizontal.  The right line is diagonal - down and to the right:
[image: Example image]
In the example image, the aperture and the path is shown in red.  The resulting geometry is shown in black.  Both of the above examples use the same aperture, but wipe it along a different path.

I'd like to be able to draw with an arbitrary shaped pen, even though the above example only shows rectangles.

I made an attempt at using the System.Drawing.2D namespace but it doesn't seem to do what I need it to do.  Using custom end-caps on pens seemed promising, but the end caps rotate with the direction of the line.  Also, getting the line-width right seems challenging.[image: failed end-caps example]

**I've considered** drawing the aperture over and over again, centered at different points along the path, but that doesn't seem performant.  It is also quite difficult to minimize the number of aperture draws.

**The best idea I've got** is to try to draw the 'line' as a filled shape.  At first, I thought a convex hull algorithm would be the answer - simply take the vertices of the aperture at the beginning of the draw and at the end of the draw and put them through a convex hull algorithm to find the 'outer' vertices.  This works for my 1st example above, - but a star-shaped aperture demonstrates that this solution is incomplete.  It only works when the aperture is convex itself.
[image]

Simply putting all of the vertices through a convex hull algorithm would result in the areas highlighted in blue being filled in, but I need to only fill in the black areas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best idea I've got involves some redundant drawing, but I think it will work.

Treat the aperture polygon as a list of line segments.  For each line segment in the list, draw a parallelogram using the line segment of the aperture *at the start of the move*, and using the same line segment of the aperture *at the end of the move*
[image: Parallelogram Draw]

The above image shows this for three of the ten line segments that make up the star.  For some pen shapes, there is potentially a lot of overlap between segments, but this method *should* result in all of the correct pixels being filled in.  Notice that most of the green area is already filled in by the blue area and the red area, with just a small section in the lower-right star that's green-only.  Redundantly filling in these pixel is wasteful, but will result in the correct image, I think.

**Other Thoughts:**

There may be a way to do this without redundantly filling in the same area, and it probably involves ray casting.  Notice how the intersection of the red and green line in the lower-right would fall on a vertex that is not part of the original aperture.  You would need to draw a ray from the right-most vertex of the right polygon along the direction of the move and find where that intersects the green line in order to draw the final shape correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This is an ugly, inelegant solution, but you could take the vector that represents the stroke direction and length and redraw your shape many times along that vector.  (You'd have to choose an interval at which to draw it that didn't leave gaps.)  This would only produce correct results if you want aliased output; it would screw up any anti-aliasing done by GDI+, because pixels with midtones would potentially be drawn over, making them darker than they should be.

Comment: Yeah, I mention that possibility in the question. You bring up some very good points about it mucking up the anti-aliasing - but that may not be a concern in this application.  I expect the final image to be monochrome.

Comment: Oops, sorry.  Guess I skimmed.  Anyway, that's the best I've got.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you're on the right path with the solution that you posed... using the individual aperture segments to create parallelograms.  However, you'll run into issues when you attempt to fill that with anything but a solid brush because you'd actually be doing repetitive fills.

The best thing to do is to create all of those polygons, just as you said, but then union them all together.  You'll end up with a single polygon representing the outline that you want, then you can simply fill it in whatever way you want.

If you're using WPF, simply use a `GeometryGroup` with all of your polygons as children, then use that group as the first geometry in a `CombinedGeometry` with 'Union' or 'Exclude' modes, passing null for the second parameter.

If you're not using WPF, you can try a library such as Clipper which has a version written in C#/.NET but is more for arbitrary drawing than just WPF.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I tackled this problem in WPF. I wanted a solution that could do complex shapes with curves and holes. The closest I got was using GetFlattenedPathGeometry on the original shape which converts curves to line segments and then running the method mentioned above. It is a lot of redundant calculations, but combining the parallelograms followed by "stamping" the original shape at the beginning and end points resulted in relatively few geometries in the final geometry.

```html
public Geometry translateGeo(Geometry baseGeo, Point translate)
{
    // sweeps a geometry linearly from current location through vector

    Debug.WriteLine("Translating Geometry");
    Debug.WriteLine("Original Outline Verticies: " + CountVerticies(baseGeo.GetFlattenedPathGeometry()));

    Geometry sweptPathGeo = baseGeo.Clone();
    Geometry capGeo = baseGeo.Clone();
   
    capGeo.Transform = new TranslateTransform(translate.X, translate.Y);
    sweptPathGeo = new CombinedGeometry(GeometryCombineMode.Union, sweptPathGeo, capGeo);
    sweptPathGeo = sweptPathGeo.GetFlattenedPathGeometry();


    geometry = sweptPathGeo.Clone();


    PathGeometry pathGeo = baseGeo.GetFlattenedPathGeometry();

    foreach (PathFigure figure in pathGeo.Figures)
    {
        Point startPoint = figure.StartPoint;
        //Debug.WriteLine(startPoint.X + ", " + startPoint.Y);
        foreach (PathSegment segment in figure.Segments)
        {
            PolyLineSegment polySegment = segment as PolyLineSegment;
            if (polySegment != null)
            {
                foreach (Point point in polySegment.Points)
                {
                    sweptPathGeo = new CombinedGeometry(GeometryCombineMode.Union, sweptPathGeo, getShadow(startPoint, point, translate));
                    startPoint = point;
                }
            }

            LineSegment lineSegment = segment as LineSegment;
            if (lineSegment != null)
            {
                sweptPathGeo = new CombinedGeometry(GeometryCombineMode.Union, sweptPathGeo, getShadow(startPoint, lineSegment.Point, translate));
                startPoint = lineSegment.Point;
            }
        }
    }

    //sweptPathGeo = sweptPathGeo.GetOutlinedPathGeometry();
    Debug.WriteLine("Finale Outline Verticies: " + CountVerticies(sweptPathGeo.GetFlattenedPathGeometry()));
    return sweptPathGeo;

}
public Geometry getShadow(Point startPoint, Point endPoint, Point translate)
{

    PointCollection points = new PointCollection();
    points.Add(startPoint);
    points.Add(endPoint);
    points.Add(new Point(endPoint.X + translate.X, endPoint.Y + translate.Y));
    points.Add(new Point(startPoint.X + translate.X, startPoint.Y + translate.Y));
    points.Add(startPoint);

    Polygon poly = new Polygon();
    poly.Points = points;
    poly.Arrange(geometry.Bounds);
    poly.Measure(geometry.Bounds.Size);

        PathGeometry returnGeo = poly.RenderedGeometry.GetOutlinedPathGeometry();

    return returnGeo;
    //foreach (Point point in points) Debug.WriteLine(point.X + ", " + point.Y);

}
private int CountVerticies(PathGeometry geo)
{
    int verticies = 0;
    foreach (PathFigure figure in geo.Figures)
    {
        Point startPoint = figure.StartPoint;
        verticies += 1;
        foreach (PathSegment segment in figure.Segments)
        {
            PolyLineSegment polySegment = segment as PolyLineSegment;
            if (polySegment != null) verticies += polySegment.Points.Count;
            
            LineSegment lineSegment = segment as LineSegment;
            if (lineSegment != null) verticies += 1;
        }
    }
    return verticies;
}
```